# Regular expression to search column in text file

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I am having trouble getting a regular expression that will search for an input term in the specified column. If the term is found in that column, then it needs to output that whole line. 
These are my variables:

```
sreg = search word  #Example: Adam
file = text file   #Example: Contacts.txt
sfield = column number   #Example: 1
```

the text file is in this format with a space being the field seperator, with many contact entries:

```
    First Last Email Phone Category    
    Adam aster junfmr@ 8473847548 word
    Jeff Williams 43wadsfddf@ 940342221995 friend
    JOhn smart qwer@qwer 999999393 enemy
    yooun yeall adada 111223123 other
    zefir sentr jjdirutk@jd 8847394578 other
```

I've tried with no success:

```
grep "$sreg" "$file" | cut -d " " -f"$sfield"-"$sfield"
awk -F, '{ if ($sreg == $sfield) print $0 }' "$file"
awk -v s="$sreg" -v c="$sfield" '$c == s { print $0 }' "$file"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thank you, added more information. A space is the field separator.

Comment: $sfield =>  1, 2, ..   need another expression to change it to $1,$2...

Comment: Your express awk -v s="$sreg" -v c="$sfield" '$c == s { print $0 }' "$file"   looks like correct....

Comment: Thank you fedorqui, didnt realize that. I will go back and accept the answers on those old questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` may be the best solution for this:

```
awk -v field="$field" -v name="$name" '$field==name' "$file"
```

This checks if the field number `$field` has the value `$name`. If so, `awk` automatically prints the full line that contains it.

For example:

```
$ field=1
$ name="Adam"
$ file="your_file"
$ awk -v field="$field" -v name="$name" '$field==name' "$file"
Adam aster junfmr@ 8473847548 word
```

As you can see, we give the parameters using `-v var="$bash_var"`, so that you can use them inside `awk`.

Also, the space is the field separator, so you don't need to specify it since it is the default.

Comment: Thank you! This helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
awk -v f="$sfield" -v reg="$sreg" '{if ($f ~ reg) {print $0}}' "$file"
```

Major problem is that you need an indirection from $sfield (ex, "1") to $($sfield) (ex, $1).

I tried using backtricks `, and also using ${!sfield}, but they don't work in awk, as awk does not accept this. Finally I found the way of passing variable into awk, converting to awk internal variabls  (using -v).

Within awk, I found you can not even access variables outside. So I had to pass $sreg as well.

Update: I think using "~" instead of "==" is better because the original requirement said matchi==ng a regular expression.

For example,
sreg=Ad

Comment: Note that `{ if (condition) {print $0}}` can be rewritten to a mere `condition`. Why? Because `awk` evaluates every expression in a way that if it is True, the current record (line) is printed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment it helps.

Comment: the compare ==, is really an equal compare? How about if we want to match an regular expression, using ~ is better?

Comment: `==` is equal compare. For regexs you have to use `~`.